# Laravel response with keyBy returns object instead and array

Tags: php, json, angularjs, rest, laravel

I'm developing a project setting a back-end RESTful API with Laravel and Front-end with angularJS.
I was returning from my controller@index the simple `all()->toArray()` like this:

A.

```php
return Response::json([
    'val' => myModel::all()->toArray()
]);
```

Then with that object in angular I could do things like `$scope.myArray=response.val` and eventually actions like `$scope.myArrayBoundToATable.push(newelement)`. The resulting JSON would be better if it is key'ed by its `id` so I changed it to:

B.

```php
return Response::json([
    'res' => myModel::all()->keyBy('id')->toArray()
]);
```

But now all functions like `.splice` and `.push` throws an error. By logging to console I could see:
With `all()->toArray()`: `[Object]` everything works fine.
with `keyBy('id')->toArray()` : `Object {1: Object}`

I have to rewrite CRUD operations on the `$scope.myVar` as a JS Object, and not as an array.

I could use method A. and iterate every element to search for an ID, but method B. allows me to access elements in a more elegant way: `$scope.myVar(ID)`.

Comment: Well yes, that's what to expect. JSON (and javascript) doesn't know associative array so it is converted into an object with a property for every id.

Comment: I think you hit the spot, I wasn't aware of this (my bad, lack of deep concepts). there's no major problem for this, I can workaround the functions to do CRUD operations to work with Non-Arrays-Objects and 'till now angular supports them pretty well (for things like ng-repeat, ng-option and alike).
Now I got into troubles implementing something like this http://codepen.io/jbltx/pen/WbdRRb/. this table directive relies on well structured JSON arrays, and for reordering, paging and stuff like that it needs arrays. I'll keep reading for better ways to handle data bound to views. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is an associative array as @lukasgieter pointed out.
For ease of consumption in the frontend just convert the associative array to a regular array using `array_values`

Here is how I handle it.

```
Response::json(['val' => array_values(myModel::all())]);
```